# Twitter Bootstrap - static nav bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I change the background color of TB's nav bar? Take a look at the top nav bar on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html. When I set `background-color: pink;` on `navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top`, nothing happens. I tried doing the same on other elements. I can't seem to change the color.

Comment: I think it's the .navbar-inner element that has the background properties attached to it. It has a background colour and a background image which is a css gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS and change the colors. You need to change: `#222222` (darker color) and `#111111` (lighter color) as they are at the different ends of the background gradient. You need to change them both.
Change `#1b1b1b` and `#252525` to something in between.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #111111);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#222222), to(#111111));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #111111);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #111111);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222, #111111);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #252525;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff222222', endColorstr='#ff111111', GradientType=0);
}

.navbar-inverse .nav .active > a, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

If you don't want gradients, just do the following and change `#1b1b1b` and `#252525` to your background color and border color respectively and `#111111` for the "selected" color.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #252525;
    filter: none;
}

.navbar-inverse .nav .active > a, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why do I need to set so many properties? Shouldn't background-color be enough?

Comment: The reason all those properties are there is to support a gradient look and feel. Edited for situation where they are not needed.

Comment: BTW, if you are tweaking your bootstrap theme, I would recommend looking at this tool: http://pikock.github.com/bootstrap-magic/

Answer (score 1):

I have altered the nav-bar using a seperate style-sheet loaded after bootstrap.css that includes

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #2a2a86; /* fallback color, place your own */

  /* Gradients for modern browsers, replace as you see fit */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3a3a96, #2a2a86);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3a3a96, #2a2a86);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#3a3a96), to(#2a2a86));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a3a96, #2a2a86);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3a3a96, #2a2a86);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3a3a96, #2a2a86);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;

  /* IE8-9 gradient filter */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3a3a96', endColorstr='#2a2a86', GradientType=0);
```

}

you can then apply the same logic to buttons and so forth.

to me it seems that the base colour is set at the base class of an element, so

```
.navbar
.btn
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
background-color: pink !important;
```